# How to make method when Value Animator end?

Tags: java, android

as i read in here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html

i still dont understand how to make onAnimationEnd listener or something to do when ValueAnimator animation end. there is a part in there said:

[image]

Anyone can explain with some example code? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(progress, seekBar.getMax());
anim.setDuration(Utility.setAnimationDuration(progress));
anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) 
    {
        int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        seekBar.setProgress(animProgress);
    }
});
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) 
    {
        // done
        //your stuff goes here
    }
});
anim.start();
```